# How to reduce horizontal spacing between subplots in matplotlib python?

Tags: python, matplotlib, size, subplot, figure

I have created a 4 rows x 2 columns plot in python.
The height space hspace reduces the vertical spacing between subplots which is fine but when I reduce the wspace thinking it is the horizontal space , it simply doesn't work.
The tight layout is also not working.

This figure is 30x30 in size

```
fig, (ax1, ax2, ax3, ax4) = plt.subplots(4,2,figsize=(30,30))
fig.tight_layout()
```

The Space is orange is what I want to reduce or remove
[image: Reduce the orange area space]

Please help :)

Comment: You are probably drawing images with the default `aspect='equal'`. Maybe you can use `aspect='auto'`?  Otherwise, you'll need to choose a narrower figsize. You either need to lose control about the whitespace or about having unstretched images.  Note that your question is missing a lot of code to be reproducible.

Comment: Thank you, let me try aspect = equal, yes the plot and histogram is not shared because it is my research work so :)

Comment: Well, you shouldn't share your private code. Instead, you are expected to create a minimal example (using test data) that reproduces your issue.  You might want to take [StackOverflow's tour](https://stackoverflow.com/tour) if you like prompt and helpful answers.

Comment: It worked with aspect ratio thank you so much <3